# How to handle touch event on a ImageView

Tags: android, touch, android-imageview

I have three Images. When I first touch, first Image is shown, when I second touch, second Image is shown, and then when I third touch, third Image is shown. After all, when I fourth touch, I want to show first Image return and so on.

Can someone point me to show how handling or touching on a ImageView of android?

Comment: try to describe your problem more effectively. an Image also helps

Comment: why don't you use an `int counter` variable... increase its value `+1` on every click, and check the count and show the image.. that's it. any problem with this method ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should do what you need:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView image;
int i=1;
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewName);      
        setButtonOnClickListeners();       
            }
        }
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                if (i==1){
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
                i++;
                }
                else if(i==2){
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
                    i++;
                }
                else if(i==3){
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
                    i++;
                }
                else if(i==4){
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image4);
                    i=1;
                }
        }
    });
```

I've not tested but the idea is correct. When you click the image it will change the drawable depending on the value of `i`. When you get image 1 `i` will equal 1. Onclick will increment `i` until `i==4` which it will reset to 1 as you requested.

A while loop might be tidier but this was the quickest soultion I thought of.

Answer (score 0):

> how to handle click on an `ImageView`

You can simply set a `View.OnClickListener` for your `ImageView`:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do stuff
        }
    });
```

Comment: I already write setOnClickListener method. How to handle touch count inside this method?

Comment: I think @SRBbans had already provide a solution. or maybe I could implement for you.

Comment: Yes, Thank You @LionHere